# How to use a fontAwesome icon for the PrimeNg Tree's toggler?

Tags: css, font-awesome, primeng, primeicons

I'm using FontAwesome in the app and I've not installed PrimeIcons.

So now when I'm using the PrimeNg's [tree](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/tree), I don't have any "chevron" displayed to open/close each item.

I cannot find a way in a documentation to override it(like a lot of their other component.

How can I replace their `pi pi-fw pi-chevron-down` by something like `fa-solid fa-chevron-down`(same for the chevron-left)?

I'm not sure how to target a CSS element to then apply another css on it?
Or did I miss a way of customizing this element?
(it's ok if it's in a global style)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .scss file, maybe could be better to set only related to involved components:

```
:host ::ng-deep {
    .pi {
        font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    }

    .pi-chevron-down:before {
        content:"\f107"
    }
}
```

in order to override other icons, please refer to fontawesome related [cheatsheet](https://fontawesome.com/v5/cheatsheet/)